# Moose object as a lazy hash

Tags: perl, lazy-evaluation, moose

I want to replace some hashes used in my program with lazy Moose objects for performance reason. The problem is, there's a lot of code that I don't control that uses, of course, `->{key}` to access elements. Such access works with Moose objects, but does not work with lazy ones before they were initialized:

```perl
package Stuff;

use Moose;

has foo => (
   lazy=>1, 
   default=> sub { +{bar=>baz} }
);

package main;
my $x = Stuff->new();

print Dumper $x->{foo}; # undef =(
print Dumper $x->foo;   # {bar => baz }
print Dumper $x->{foo}; # {bar => baz }
```

Any way to make that first `$x->{foo}` initialize the variable?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Moose seems possibly useful

Comment: @AKHolland bingo! Care to make it into answer so I can accept?

Comment: Changed it into answer form. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use it as a hash directly, but with [Tie::Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Moose) you can create a hash which calls the underlying Moose methods. You can pass this hash along to your other code.

```
use Tie::Moose;

my $x = Stuff->new();
tie my %x, "Tie::Moose", $x;

print Dumper($x{foo}); # { 'bar' => 'baz' }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want code to run whenever a element of your hash object is accessed? That's possible using [magic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Variable::Magic), but it will greatly slow down access to your object.

Comment: Slower than something like `return $x->{foo} //= $x->foo()` ?

Comment: Yes, because the alternative would have to do that in addition to a sub call.